# Can I put my python GUI made in wxpython on a web browser?

Tags: python, web, frameworks, wxpython

I have a GUI which I wrote in wxpython which runs on my PC.

Now, I want to be able to port the program so that it can run from a browser, and I will be able to access it remotely.

Is it possible to do this with wxpython? If not, is it possible to port the program in some way so that it runs from the browser but isn't the main page? Ideally, I don't want to have to rewrite any of the GUI code.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately app engines such as Google App Engine doesn't support wxpython, Tkinter or such modules

Comment: @KDawG but they do support wxwidgets I thought? There has been a recent update which makes it look as though wxPython is now supported within a browser? http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15291

Comment: sorry dude they simply don't...

Answer (score 0):

There's been some talk of doing something like this on the wxPython users list, but nothing has come of it that I'm aware of. You can read some more about the stuff that that ticket refers to here:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/RPpt9IqzGpo

However, it sounds like it uses wxPython Phoenix, which itself is pretty beta as it doesn't have all the functionality (or widgets) that classic does. If you want to create a web page with Python, you would be better off using a Python web framework such as Django, TurboGears, Sphinx, bottle, flask or one of the others.

If you want to create a web browser with wxPython, try the webview widget.